# Download a file via SSh to local machine

Tags: ssh, scp

I am using Linux Mint 21.2 and I have set up a remote server.
I can upload files to it via SSH by using
`scp local/path/file.txt username@remoteserver.com:/destinationfolder`.

I am told that I can do it the other way round, also.
But when I enter
`scp username@remoteserver.com:/destinationfolder/file.txt /` and then hit TAB, it only shows me the folders on the remote machine.
I expected it to show my local folders.
Since I don't want to destroy any files on my machines I wanted to ask first what I have to do now.

Comment: `/` is not your directories, but the root of your OS. Try `./` then `tab` instead... `scp username@remoteserver.com:/destinationfolder/file.txt ./`

Comment: @GillesQuénot Then I am only shown the content of the remote folder that I am in.

Comment: _I am told that I can do it the other way round_: if you `ssh` the other side, yes

Comment: @GillesQuénot Huh? I want to download a file from a server to whom I am connect via SSH.

Comment: The problem is that OP is running the correct command, but on the wrong side. You have to run this command in a *local* shell, not a *remote* one.

Comment: Otherwise, if you really must initiate this from the remote and your client address is routable for the remote, then see [this answer on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639564)

Comment: @Panki Oh my, that worked! Doing it in a local terminal did the trick! Thank you!